# Python not recognizing pandas while using my user defined function from another file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, import

I am currently trying to create two files for a project, one that cleans and formats my raw data `cleanfile.py` with a function `clean(df1, df2)` which returns one joined clean dataframe, and another file `analysis.ipynb` where I can do analysis on said dataframe.  I tried using the following

```
from cleanfile import clean

df = clean(df1, df2)
```

But when doing so I recieve the error

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

My function `clean` does involve pandas functions.  I have imported pandas as pd in `analysis.ipynb` and I've tried importing pandas both inside and outside of the function in `cleanfile.py`.  The clean function works when I simply define the function in a code cell in `analysis.ipynb`, so I know that it works, but the function is around 100 lines of code that I will be using on several different projects so I felt that keeping the function code separate so that I could import it when needed would be more efficient and organized.

Comment: What happens if you try `from cleanfile import *`

Answer (score 0):

pandas is imported in `cleanfile` but not in current file.

just add:

```
import pandas as pd
```

using star import `from cleanfile import *` is not recommended. It pollutes the namespace and bad for readability.

Comment: I have already imported pandas as pd in my working file `analysis.ipynb`

Comment: are you sure you ran the cell? try to run it again. If the kernel was interrupted, or you ended the process, the memory will be emptied, but cells will remain as text.

Comment: While import * might not be recommended it might help do some troubleshooting with determining if a name was incorrectly spelled. Please do not simply right off other peoples suggestions because they are not what you believe to be the correct course

Comment: It is not recommended period. not forbidden or illegal, but not recommended. I use it all the time when working on my scripts, but that doesn't change the fact that it's generally a bad practice.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with that, I wanted him to do import * to see if it worked in a general sense and then narrow it down. The tone of your answer was disregard the import * comment I made earlier.